# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, What could be the problem?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, constraints, ddl

I try to add  a constraint , but it gave me the error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

What could be the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE "BDCOMEARE"."PILOTE" (
  "matrPlt" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
  "nomPlt" VARCHAR2(50) ,
  "prenomPlt" VARCHAR2(50) ,
  "gradePlt" VARCHAR2(100) ,
  "adressePlt" VARCHAR2(100) ,
  "salairePlt" NUMBER(10,2) ,
  "dateEmbauche" DATE ,
  PRIMARY KEY ("matrPlt")
)

ALTER TABLE PILOTE ADD CONSTRAINT check_gradePlt
    CHECK (gradePlt IN 'commandantBord', 'assistantBord','officier');
```

Comment: You are missing a closing paren.

Comment: By the way, you should not in general use double-quotes. `"BDCOMEARE"."PILOTE"` is the same thing as `BDCOMEARE.PILOTE` anyway, and `"matrPlt"` forces you to refer to it with the exact same case and quoting every time, forever (e.g. `select matrPlt from pilote` will fail with ORA-00904 Invalid identifier). In fact that's another issue with your check constraint - it refers to a column named `gradePlt` but you just named it `"gradePlt"`. Best practice is to stick with standard Oracle naming.

Comment: i think this is the query generated via some reporting tool usually it looks alike the above qouted

Comment: `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` is always a syntax error. It may mean you have dropped a right hand bracket, as you have done here. A decent code editor (like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.6.1.html) makes it trivial to find these things. Sometimes it means we have a stray comma or rogue keyword where the compiler was expecting a parenthesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just that you need brackets after IN clause

```
CONSTRAINT check_gradePlt CHECK (
  gradePlt IN ('commandantBord', 'assistantBord', 'officier')
);
```